# Visual basic sql command not returning anything to variables

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

i am working on this code that is going to query a database for an entry and return the value of the tracking number and the time to print on a label if the tracking number exist in the databse. it does not right now it only seems to reprint the number that is enetered in a text box and it does not grab the date. any ideas? here is the code.

```
    Dim TrNum As String = Me.DupTNText.Text
    Dim TrDate As <=something if it is even needed

    Dim connectionString As String = "Data Source=XXXXX;Initial Catalog=YYYYY;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False;Encrypt=False" 

    Dim cmdText As String = "SELECT TrackingNumber, Date" & _ 
                        "FROM YYYYY " & _ 
                        "WHERE TrackingNumber = @TrackingNumber, Date = @Date" 

    Using connection As New SqlClient.SqlConnection(connectionString) 

    Dim cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand(cmdText, connection) 

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TrackingNumber", TrNum) 
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", TrDate) 

    connection.Open() 

    'this is where my print code begins and it works fine it just uses TrNum for the tracking number and TrDate for the date.
```

Here is my edited code with the changes applied, am i getting closer?

```
    Dim dupText
    Dim trackingNumber As String
    Dim dateSent

    dupText = Me.DupTNText

    Dim connectionString As String = "Data Source=XXXXX;Initial Catalog=YYYYY;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False;Encrypt=False"

    Dim cmdText As String = "SELECT TrackingNumber, Date" & _
                            "FROM YYYYY " & _
                            "WHERE TrackingNumber = @TrackingNumber, Date = @Date"

    Using connection As New SqlClient.SqlConnection(connectionString)

        Dim cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand(cmdText, connection)

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TrackingNumber", dupText)
        cmd.Parameters("@TrackingNumber").Direction = ParameterDirection.Input

        connection.Open()

        Dim sdr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

        If (sdr("TrackingNumber") IsNot Nothing) Then
            trackingNumber = Convert.ToString(sdr("TrackingNumber"))
            dateSent = Convert.ToString(sdr("Date"))
        End If
```

**EDIT #3**

Changes Applied, i am pretty sure its the query string now. i get

> "The parameterized query '(@TrackingNumber nvarchar(4000),@Date datetime)SELECT TrackingNu' expects the parameter '@TrackingNumber', which was not supplied."

witht the string as it is below. What other part of the code would you need to see to help determine the problem? I feel like i am close and thanks i am learning a bunch from this! sorry also for the change of variable names.

```
Private Sub DupOKButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles DupOKButton.Click

    Dim dupText
    Dim trackingNumber As String
    Dim dateSent

    dupText = Me.DupTNText

    Dim connectionString As String = "Data Source=XXXXX;Initial Catalog=ScannedDB;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False;Encrypt=False"

    Dim cmdText As String = "SELECT TrackingNumber, Date FROM[ScannedDBTable] WHERE TrackingNumber = @TrackingNumber AND Date = @Date"

    Using connection As New SqlClient.SqlConnection(connectionString)

        Dim cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand(cmdText, connection)

        cmd.Parameters.Add(CreateSqlParameter("@TrackingNumber", DbType.String, ParameterDirection.Input, trackingNumber))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(CreateSqlParameter("@Date", DbType.DateTime, ParameterDirection.Input, dateSent))

        connection.Open()

        Dim sdr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

        If (sdr("TrackingNumber") IsNot Nothing) Then
            trackingNumber = Convert.ToString(sdr("TrackingNumber"))
            dateSent = Convert.ToString(sdr("Date"))
        End If

'Printing code...
```

EDIT #4

```
Private Sub DupOKButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles DupOKButton.Click


    Dim trackingNumber As String
    Dim dateSent As DateTime

    trackingNumber = Me.DupTNText.Text

    Dim connectionString As String = "Data Source=XXXXX;Initial Catalog=ScannedDB;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False;Encrypt=False"

    Dim cmdText As String = "SELECT TrackingNumber, Date FROM[ScannedDBTable] WHERE TrackingNumber = @TrackingNumber AND Date = @Date"

    Using connection As New SqlClient.SqlConnection(connectionString)



        Dim cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand(cmdText, connection)

        cmd.Parameters.Add(CreateSqlParameter("@TrackingNumber", DbType.String, ParameterDirection.Input, trackingNumber))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(CreateSqlParameter("@Date", DbType.DateTime, ParameterDirection.Input, dateSent))

        connection.Open()

        Dim sdr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

        If (sdr("TrackingNumber") IsNot Nothing) Then
            trackingNumber = Convert.ToString(sdr("TrackingNumber"))
            dateSent = Convert.ToString(sdr("Date"))
        End If
```

EDIT #5

```
Private Sub DupOKButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles DupOKButton.Click


    Dim trackingNumber As String
    Dim dateSent As DateTime

    trackingNumber = Me.DupTNText.Text

    Dim connectionString As String = "Data Source=XXXXX;Initial Catalog=ScannedDB;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False;Encrypt=False"

    Dim cmdText As String = "SELECT TrackingNumber, [Date] FROM ScannedDBTable WHERE TrackingNumber = @TrackingNumber"

    Using connection As New SqlClient.SqlConnection(connectionString)

        Dim cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand(cmdText, connection)

        cmd.Parameters.Add(CreateSqlParameter("@TrackingNumber", DbType.String, ParameterDirection.Input, trackingNumber))
        'cmd.Parameters.Add(CreateSqlParameter("@Date", DbType.DateTime, ParameterDirection.Input, dateSent))

        connection.Open()

        Dim sdr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

        If (sdr("TrackingNumber") IsNot Nothing) Then
            trackingNumber = Convert.ToString(sdr("TrackingNumber"))
            dateSent = Convert.ToString(sdr("Date"))
        Else
        End If
```

Comment: Do you even make a call to the `cmd.ExecuteReader()` method?

Comment: @Will Marcouiller Here are some changes i made

Comment: In your code, you're not providing any data type to your variables `dupText` and `dateSent`. This might cause a null (nothing) value when converted, so this would complaint about parameter not provided. Plus, it seems it's watching for two `nvarchar(4000)` data types as parameters, so change your `SqlParameter.DbType` to the appropriate type and test it. Try using `QuickWatch` to see what happens just before the query is executed against the database.

Comment: @Will Marcouiller im not sure of the datatype for the dupText because it pulls the entry from a text box so string wont work and text is too vauge, i changed datesent to a DateTime and it is now seeing the right data types. i used quick launch and it is indeed erroring out because of a null value. i modified my code and posted it above. i think i am attcking this wrong. if i can convert the entry in the textbox to a string and use the code above i think i am there. the only thing is, is that even a possibility?

Comment: The `TextBox.Text` property is `String` typed. The `dateSent` variable value should be picked through a `DateTimePicker` control, if you're going WinForms. Then, your `DateTimePicker.Value` is a `DateTime` type. So, you're `dateSent` variable should be `DateTime`. Yet, you should first consider your data table columns data types, as this is with what the RDBMS has to deal. It seems it's waiting for `nvarchar(4000)`, so try `DbType.String`.

Comment: @Will Marcouiller Oh man so close, i forgot the .text on the DupTNText so i added it and tried to run it and it gave me an error saying "SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM." but at least we know it is trying to get the data now and using what is entered. i have the Date setup as datetime on the sql server, is it getting confused because i am only typing in a tracking number and asking for a tracking number and a date and time? also i tried changing the datetime dbtype to string and got "Invalid attempt to read when no data is present."

Comment: Please see my last edit for an answer. =)

Comment: @Will Marcouiller I commented out the @Date parameter and changed the query to what is above. i do need the output to give a tracking number in a variable and the date in a seperate variable, it is just the nature of how the printing SDK needs it. I get an error that says "Invalid attempt to read when no data is present." at the "If (sdr("TrackingNumber") IsNot Nothing) Then" line. the entry i am using to test it is most deffinatly in the database so the app must not be talking to it correctly. i am very grateful for all of the time you are spending on this.

Comment: That must be because you do not seem to look whether there is data returned in the reader: `If (Not sdr.HasRows) Then Return`. After this line, you may assume that there is information datum, so that you may write `If (sdr.Read()) Then ' Place your variable assignments here... End If`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dim TrNum As String = Me.DupTNText.Text  
Dim TrDate As <=something if it is even needed  

Dim connectionString As String = "Data Source=XXXXX;Initial Catalog=YYYYY;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False;Encrypt=False"   

Dim cmdText As String = "SELECT TrackingNumber, Date " & _   
                    "FROM YYYYY " & _   
                    "WHERE TrackingNumber = @TrackingNumber, Date = @Date"   

Using connection As SqlConnection = New SqlClient.SqlConnection(connectionString)   

    Using cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlClient.SqlCommand(cmdText, connection)   

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TrackingNumber", TrNum)   
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", TrDate)   
        cmd.Parameters("@TrackingNumber").Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
        cmd.Parameters("@Date").Direction = ParameterDirection.Input

        connection.Open()   

        Dim sdr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        If (sdr.HasRows) Then _
            While (sdr.Read())
                '' Printing data
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Track#: {0}, Date: {1}" _
                    , Convert.ToString(sdr("TrackingNumber")) _
                    , DateTime.Parse(Convert.ToString(sdr("Date")), New CultureInfo("en-Us"))
            End While
    End Using
End Using
```

***Disclaimer:*** This code hasn't been tested and is provided as-is to simply demonstrate an idea that, let's hope so, will guide you to your solution.

Please see [`SqlCommand.ExecuteReader Method`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kcbe65k.aspx) for further details on the topic.

**EDIT #1**

> how would the sdr feed the tracking number and date to separate variables?

You would simply feed your variables like so:

```
' Assuming you have already declared your variables here...'
If (sdr("TrackingNumber") IsNot Nothing) Then 
    trackingNumber = Convert.ToString(sdr("TrackingNumber"))
    dateSent = DateTime.Parse(Convert.ToString(sdr("Date")), New CultureInfo("en-CA"))
End If
```

This is just an example. You don't have to use `DateTime.Parse` unless you want the full format control over your `DateTime` regional settings.

**EDIT #2**

> @dretzlaff17 where would that go? (speaking of ParameterDirection enum)

You would put it exactly where you're calling the `Parameters.AddWithValue()` method. Instead of calling the method like you're actually doing, you might as well do the following:

```
Dim trackingNumberParameter As SqlParameter = New SqlParameter()
trackingNumberParameter.ParameterName = "@TrackingNumber"
trackingNumberParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
trackingNumberParameter.Value = TrNum

cmd.Parameters.Add(trackingNumberParameter)

Dim dateParameter As SqlParameter = New SqlParameter()
...

cmd.Parameters.Add(dateParameter)
```

Or even like so, which might better suits your code:

```
cmd.Parameters("@TrackingNumber").Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
```

Please see my code sample revision with the ParameterDirection enum above (initial sample).

**EDIT #3**

> "The parameterized query '(@TrackingNumber nvarchar(4000),@Date nvarchar(4000))SELECT (@Tr' expects the parameter '@TrackingNumber', which was not supplied." when the query is "SELECT (@TrackingNumber) FROM[XXXXX] WHERE TrackingNumber = @TrackingNumber"

This seems, at first view, that the data types are not the right. I may be wrong as I don't know your code.

If that is so, you might also provide the [`DbType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dbtype.aspx) of your parameters.

```
cmd.Parameters("@TrackingNumber").DbType = SqlDbType.String
cmd.Parameters("@Date").DbType = SqlDbType.DateTime ' If the data column is indeed a DateTime data type.
```

But what I would do to make sure I provided the parameters respectively, is what I have written in **EDIT #2**, that is, the first section when declaring and creating instances of `SqlParameter` for both parameters, and specifying their respective data type throught the [`DbType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.dbtype.aspx) property. (See [SqlParameter Members](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter_members.aspx) for more details). Perhaps a helper method could do the job for you, as you might want to do the same with other queries as well.

```
Public Function CreateSqlParameter(ByVal name As String, ByVal dbType As DbType, ByVal direction As ParameterDirection, ByVal value As Object) As SqlParameter
    Dim parameter As SqlParameter = New SqlParameter()
    parameter.ParameterName = name
    parameter.DbType = dbType
    parameter.Direction = direction
    parameter.Value = value
    Return parameter
End Function
```

And then creating them within your code:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(CreateSqlParameter("@TrackingNumber", DbType.String, ParameterDirection.Input, TrNum))
cmd.Parameters.Add(CreateSqlParameter("@Date", DbType.DateTime, ParameterDirection.Input, TrDate))
```

Neverhelss, check for the InnerException as it might provide further details on the error. The least I can say is that you have progressed.

**EDIT #4**

Perhaps this might help: [`The parameterized query ... expects the parameter ..., which was not supplied.`](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-IE/sqldataaccess/thread/77547dd8-0090-4b14-9f57-dcf0d6c9dea4)

**EDIT #5**

> "SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM." Is it getting confused because i am only typing in a tracking number and asking for a tracking number and a date and time?

Yes, it is somehow getting confused. The defaut value of a non-nullable DateTime data type is:

```
Dim dateSent As DateTime
```

dateSent already has a value which is `01, January 0001 00:00:00.000 AM` as per MSDN reference about the [`DateTime Structure`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx). Since the SQL Server DateTime data type covers the period specified in the error message, the `@dateSent` DateTime variable cannot be earlier than `1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM`, it complains about an value out of range.

If you don't feel like the DateTime parameter is required, just remove it from the query, and subtract the code adding this parameter to your `cmd` variable. Use only what is necessary for you to get the information you need. If this is the tracking number, then only use the `@TrackingNumber` parameter. So, your SQL DQL might look like :

```
select TrackingNumber
        , [Date]
    from YYYYY
    where TrackingNumber = @TrackingNumber
```

Then, there will no longer be the need for the @Date parameter. But then again, only you know whether you need this parameter or not. But since you do not provide any value to it, it seems to me that you don't need it.

Comment: @Will Marcouiller Thanks! Then how would the sdr feed the tracking number and date to seperate variables? the reason i ask is all i have to do to get the printer to print is put in the variable name for both the tracking number and the date.

Comment: @Will Marcouiller Thanks again! and i dont need full control of the regional settings. you have been such a big help! This code would be replacing the code below right?        
    If (sdr.HasRows) Then _ 
            While (sdr.Read()) 
                '' Printing data 
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Track#: {0}, Date: {1}" _ 
                    , Convert.ToString(sdr("TrackingNumber")) _ 
                    , DateTime.Parse(Convert.ToString(sdr("Date")), New CultureInfo("en-Us")) 
            End While

Comment: @0bfus: Yes, this is where you would set your variables for the obtained result of the TrackingNumber and Date. Consider that there might be some `Nothing` handling to perform to avoid some type casting errors, but that should be fine.

Comment: @Will Marcouiller i added a rough up of the new code with the changes suggested. would you take a look at it?

Comment: @Will Marcouiller  I tried running tha bove code and it hangs at the "Dim sdr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()" line. it gives an "Incorrect syntax near ','." error. any ideas?

Comment: @0bfus: This kind of error message comes from the underlying data store. Verify whether all of the required spaces needed are there within your query. I suspect that the FROM keyword is concatenated with the selected Data data column name.

Comment: @Will Marcouiller Here is my exact query "SELECT TrackingNumber, [date] FROM XXXXX WHERE TrackingNumber = @TrackingNumber, Date = @Date". does it look right?

Comment: @Will Marcouiller If i play with it a bit i get "The parameterized query '(@TrackingNumber nvarchar(4000),@Date nvarchar(4000))SELECT (@Tr' expects the parameter '@TrackingNumber', which was not supplied." when the query is "SELECT (@TrackingNumber) FROM[XXXXX] WHERE TrackingNumber = @TrackingNumber"

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, this line here:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", TrDate)
```

Sets the `@Date` parameter in the query to the value of `TrDate`.  It does not pull out a value into `TrDate`.

Secondly I can't see where you actually call `cmd.Execute()` and retrieve the result set, is that further on in the code?

Comment: You're right for the `@Date` thing, however the SQL SELECT statement makes so by selecting the `Date` data column, I guess. =)

Comment: how do you pull @Date into TrDate then? also cmd.execute() is not a part of the system.data.sqlclcient.sqlcommand according to visual studio

Comment: @0bfus: `cmd.Execute()` is not, but `cmd.ExecuteQuery()` is.

Comment: @Will Marcouiller it still isnt recognizing .executequery(). do i need anything other than imports system.data.sqlclient?

Comment: @0bfus: My mistake, sorry! It is `cmd.ExecuteReader()`

Comment: @Obfus - Will's code shows you the principal, try `ExecuteReader()` instead: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/182ax5k8.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you set the direction property on your parameter object

```
myParm.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
```

or

```
myParm.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
```

Comment: +1 Parameter direction is indeed important to notice. Thanks! =)

Comment: In your case it would look like this.  

cmd.Parameters["@TrackingNumber"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

Comment: I would also recommend moving your command text to a stored procedure, and declaring output parameters.